# How can I Sort and Merge PDFs using PHP and pdftk

Tags: php, sorting, pdftk

I have a PHP program that fetches alot of individual PDFs from backend and save into a folder.

Currently I am using pdfk to merge the pdfs. Below is the sample code used:

```
exec("pdftk.exe *.pdf cat output merged.pdf");
```

How do I merge them according to a particular order, 1st fetched as first page to last fetched as the last page?

Answer (score 0):

You can read directory and check the creation timestamp of the file with `filemtime()`
Maybe iterate trough files and put the times and filenames in array and then sort the array and then create binding pdf

[filemtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Comment: I have tried this but how to pass in the array into the pdftk command? Now I use *.pdf to signify all pdfs in the directory. Meaning I must create a very long string with the pdf names and pass that in?

Comment: did you saw this article I think it might help you. I personally always use tcpdf for pdf creation - http://www.johnboy.com/blog/merge-multiple-pdf-files-with-php